# Is "ManagedThreadId" good to test locks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I am performing some tests on some code that uses `lock`, I was wondering if:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
```

is this correct way to test the multi-threads access to that locked code?

Comment: The lock owner is indeed internally marked with the ManagedThreadId.  Rather academic, you can't get to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, because int is not what is [defined in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

> Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private
>   static object variable to protect data common to all instances.

I would like to suggest to add new object field and it will satisfy MSDN requirements.